# Changing a Image source file using php

Tags: php, upload, submit, photo

I want to basically make a simple picture upload, then change the first picture to the newly uploaded photo

Php code: (commented for your helping)

```
<?php

//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
 define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file  is an     image by checking the extension.
function getExtension($str) {
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; }
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
}

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errror occures.

//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
 //checks if the form has been submitted
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {

//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

//if it is not empty
if ($image) 
{

//get the original name of the file from the clients machine
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

//get the extension of the file in a lower case format
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

//if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not      upload the file,  
//otherwise we will do more tests
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") &&              ($extension != "gif")) 
    {

//print error message

echo "";

        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
//get the size of the image in bytes
//$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
//in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
$size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
echo "";

$errors=1;
}
//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;

//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;

//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
echo "";

$errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
{
echo "";
}

?>
```

-The Photo Div.

```
<div id="photo1div">
<img id="photo1" src=""  alt="No Image" width="251" height="146" />
</div>
```

-The Buttons (Upload and Browse)

```
<form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
  <table>
  <tr><td><table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Submit" id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload image"     onclick"load_images()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

-If you have a better way I could do this (like jquery or ajax)
Please by all means tell me how

**The Php and all are in the same file (.php ext.)**

So review:

When I click Browse and choose a image it saves to a directory folder called "image"/ then When I click submit I want it to change the Image source (photo1) to the Image I just uploaded.

Any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks 
     -Julian

Comment: I mean, go through the questions you have **already** asked, and accept some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

In your page where you have the form elements:-

```
  <form id="imageUploadForm" action="storeImage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

         <input  type="file"name="imgFile" >  

         <input type="submit value="Upload">

  </form>
```

In your `storeImage.php` do the following

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"&&isset($_REQUEST["imgFile"]))
{          
   $name=$_FILES["imgFile"]["name"];

   $tempName=$_FILES["imgFile"]["tmp_name"]; // temporary location

   $size=$_FILES["imgFile"]["size"];

   $type=$_FILES["imgFile"]["type"];

   if(($type=="image/jpg"||$type=="image/jpeg"||$type=="image/png")&&($size>0&&$size<=4096000))
   {

      $dir="thisImageFolder";  //folder name in your current directory where the file will be stored

      $fullDirectory=$dir;

      $realPath=$dir."/".$name;

       if(is_dir($fullDirectory))  //if directory exists then move the file to this plae
       {
        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $realPath);


       }
       else   //else make the directory and the move the file to this place
       {
        mkdir($fullDirectory,0777,true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $realPath);

       }

         header("Location:backToMyPage.php");  //takes the user back to this page.
   }


    else
{  
  print "File not of an image type or has exceeded size limit";  
} 
}
```

When you get back to the page, simply use the relative path to the image and it will be loaded.

Comment: Read the very bottom of my question, The php and all other material are in the same file (photo_upload.php)

Comment: then just replace the `action` of the form to "" to make it self-submit to the same script

Comment: thats not a programming question. I dont know why you would ask that

Comment: All of your text in your example you gave me was red, Maybe a missing " in your example?

Comment: look within                                                                                                if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST&&isset($_REQUEST["imgFile"]))
{                                                                      Your missing a " within that area

Comment: also, I have the pic uploading to a directory just fine, what exactly I'm asking for it that when the pic is uploaded it makes the Picture (photo1 shown above) source equal the new directoy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8654/discussion-between-ladiesman217-and-julian-neill)